# how to apply a multi threading to process List<MyDto> 5 dto objects at atime

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Need different thoughts on below scenario, assume got a `ResultSet` object from `Statement`'s `execute()` method, This `ResultSet` object may contain thousands of records, here I am updating the each `ResultSet` object's data into a DTO object.

Got the `List<MyDTO> myDTOList`, now I want to process each DTO in a thread and at a time max of 5 threads i.e 5 DTO objects.

(Remaining DTO's should wait to complete at least one thread execution, if one thread completes it's job want to add another thread, so it's again 5 threads are running.. so process will go on for all the DTO objects)

What are the available ways to implement this kind of requirement?

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions.

Comment: This is some thing like real time scenario of atm machines, there are 5 atm machines are inside but hundreds of users are waiting to access it. but at a time only 5 can access.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public class YourTask implements Callable<String> {

//Ctor
YourTask(data) {
   // save data in member variables
}

public String call() throws Exception {
    // Process data
    // return string

}

}

ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); 
List<java.util.concurrent.Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();


for (your data) {
    futures.add(threadPool.submit(new YourTask(pass_data)));
}

// Wait for threads to finish i.e. join them
for (Future<String> f :futures){
        try {
            String c = f.get();
            doneCount++;

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            //
        }
            }
```

Comment: perfect.. thanks.. after done with all threads the controller is not coming out from the program, nee to put any thing for that?

Comment: if(doneCount == testDTOList.size()){
              System.out.println("Done with ALL Threads... ");
              System.exit(0);
             }

Comment: kept that in for loop, is that fine to stop the controller?

Comment: Your controller will be stuck in the `for (futures)` loop until all threads finish and then doneCount will be equal to your DTO size.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutorService` with a fixed thread pool is designed specially for such tasks:

```
// Task that will process DTOs
public class DTOTask implements Callable<Void> {
    private MyDTO obj;

    public DTOTask(MyDTO obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() {
        // Process obj here
    };
}

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

Future<?> future = executor.submit(new DTOTask(myDObject));
```

You can use `future`s to cancel tasks, wait for their completion, retrieve results and do other things.